# Select distinct with join and group by

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

I'm trying to run the query:

```
Select Distinct table2.columnA columnA_0 ,
        table3.columnB columnB_1 ,
        table2.columnC columnC_2
  From table4 Join table1 on table4.columnD = table1.columnD
          Left Outer  Join table2 on table2.columnD = table1.columnD
          Left Outer  Join table3 on table3.columnE = table2.columnE
          where table2.columnA IS NOT NULL
          group by dbo.table2.columnA
```

but I am receiving the error

```
Column 'table3.columnB' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Why are you using `distinct` and `group by`?  SQL Server requires all columns in the select list to be in a group by if it is not in an aggregate function.  Remove the group by.

Comment: what is the intention of group by if you are not using aggregates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHY is that all columns in the select portion of your query (`table2.columnA columnA_0,  table3.columnB columnB_1, table2.columnC columnC_2`) must be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, *OR* be used in an aggregate function like SUM, MIN, MAX, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This would be because you are explicitly grouping by `table2.columnA`, yet some of the values in the select clause are neither aggregated nor grouped. Since you want distinct values (based on your inclusion of the distinct keyword), simply remove the `group by` clause.

If you have previously used MySQL, this may be new to you - MySQL allows the inclusion of unaggregated, ungrouped columns in the select clause of a grouped query; most other RDBMSs do not.

Comment: Yes, I have used mysql, but have to use sql server now. There have been a few things that I have found to be quite annoying so far. Thank you for the response. :-)